# "You were wrong before" vs. "you have been wrong before"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *you were wrong before* and *you have been wrong before*? For example:

> Person A: I'll make the right decision.
>
> Person B: Nah. You were wrong before/you've been wrong before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, *you were wrong before* suggests that the speaker is referring to a particular occasion.

*You have been wrong before* means 'There have been some occasions in the past when you have made a wrong decision'.